# Spring MVC: "No mapping for [...] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, dispatcher

Can someone help me. In Spring MVC I'm getting the error

- **WARNING: No mapping for [/TechBooks/details.htm] in
  DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**

1) First of all, in **web.xml**, I use the standard DispatcherServlet which intercepts all *.htm, nothing unusual here, this was pre-written for me:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2) In **dispatcher-servlet.xml**, I am using the **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping**, again this is standard and pre-written:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

3) Also in **dispatcher-servlet.xml**, I define my FormController class called "DetailsFormController", that maps to **details.htm**:

```
<bean name="/details.htm" class="techbooks.web.DetailsFormController"/>
```

4) And the class DetailsFormController is a FormController for a form.

```
package techbooks.web;

public class DetailsFormController extends SimpleFormController {
    ....
    }
```

When I execute the resource **/details.htm**, however, I get the above error.

- **WARNING: No mapping for [/TechBooks/details.htm] in
  DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your bean difinition to

```
     <bean name="/TechBooks/details. htm"  class="techbooks.web.DetailsFormController"/>
```

Or write a urlmapping handler for TechBooks

Comment: Thanks. I changed it like you said. Same error:

No mapping for [/TechBooks/details.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was.

When using the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, the Controller name has to be **DetailsController**, not DetailsFormController, so it maps automatically to the right JSP.

Comment: I'm confused, is DetailsController your class or another class? What is DetailsFormController?